# When inserting information to database table in Laravel, can I leave a certain table column empty?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Lets say I have a table images. Two of the table columns are upvotes and downvotes. Do I need to insert 0 as default values when populating the table or can I omit the `$image->upvotes = 0;` and `$image->downvotes = 0;`

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function postUploadImage(Request $request){
        $name = $request['name'];
        $description = $request['description'];
        $file = $request->file('image');

        $image = new Image();
        $image->name = $name;
        $image->description = $description;
        $image->file_name = 'dasdasd';
        $image->upvotes = 0;
        $image->downvotes = 0;
        $image->views = 0;
        $request->user()->images()->save($image);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

......

My migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('file_name');
            $table->string('upvotes');
            $table->string('downvotes');
            $table->string('views');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Depends on whether you defined the column to have a default value or not when you created the table.

Comment: Well I have included my migration in my question. I guess I haven't defined anything like that.

Comment: fieild which would be optional must have [default value](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#columns)

Comment: If you mark them as `->nullable()` or with a `->default(...)` then you can omit them and they will be null or have the default value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on your database structure. Use [column modifiers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#column-modifiers) in your migration to do this.

In your case, it makes sense to set the column to default to `0`. For example:

```
Schema::table('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
    $table->integer('upvotes')->default(0);
    $table->integer('downvotes')->default(0);
});
```

You can then simply omit setting these properties in your controller.

---

If you can not simply drop the table and recreate it (maybe it's already running in production and you would like to keep the existing data), make another migration to modify the existing table by doing this:

```
Schema::table('images', function ($table) {
    $table->integer('upvotes')->default(0)->change();
    $table->integer('downvotes')->default(0)->change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to set the field value as 0 you can use the below code:

```
Schema::table('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // ...
        $table->integer('upvotes')->default(0);
        $table->integer('downvotes')->default(0);
    });
```

If you wish to keep the field value as empty you can use the below code:

```
  Schema::table('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // ...
        $table->integer('upvotes')->nullable();
        $table->integer('downvotes')->nullable();
    });
```